# Clone Table Row with drop down not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, dropdown

I am trying to clone a row from a template, *with selected values*. I also want to *reset the template row after the clone*.

```
$("CloneButton").click(function() {

 var clonedRow = $('#rowtemplate').clone();
            clonedRow.html($(clonedRow).html().replace(/#/g, index));
            clonedRow.find('.project').text(project);
            clonedRow.find('.billingcodeCssId').val(timeCodeID);
            clonedRow.find('.billingcodeCss').text(timeCode);
            $('#Maintable').append(clonedRow.find('tr'));
});
```

When I try to [clone the table row JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nooberz/vbeghkdh/17/), the selector is not picking up the selector. 
Whats wrong with selector, and **how to clone the row with drop down with the *selected values*?**

Comment: change `$("CloneButton")` to `$("#CloneButton")`

Comment: @aje I fixed that selector but its still not working,

Comment: Until `index`, `project` etc are defined, the click handler is bound to throw.
You are also missing a '#' from `$("#CloneButton")`.

Comment: Also, don't use ids in cloned rows. Work exclusively with classes.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**
There will be many changes needed in your code ..

1. you wrote `$("CloneButton").click(function() {` - it misses the `#` ID selector - so your button click will not fire. You need to write `$("#CloneButton").click(function() {`
2. You need to set `selectd` attribute for both dropdown before you clone and append. You can set `selected` attribute using `.attr("selected", true)`

Below code is working fine for me. **Check Working Code Snippet**

```js
$("#CloneButton").click(function() {

var drp1Value = $('#rowtemplate tr').find('select').eq(0).val();
$("option[value=" + drp1Value + "]", $('#rowtemplate tr').find('select').eq(0))
  .attr("selected", true).siblings()
  .removeAttr("selected");
  

var drp2Value = $('#rowtemplate tr').find('select').eq(1).val();

$("option[value=" + drp2Value + "]", $('#rowtemplate tr').find('select').eq(1))
  .attr("selected", true).siblings()
  .removeAttr("selected");



 var clonedRow = $('#rowtemplate tr').clone(); 
 $('#Maintable').append(clonedRow);           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 >Main Table</h4>

<table id="Maintable" >
<th>Client</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Total</th><th>Delete?</th>
<tr>
 <td>
<span class="project"> <select class="form-control projectcodeid" id="Records_0__SelectedProjectFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedProjectFromList"><option value="">Modeling</option>
<option value="1">Ventosanzap</option>
<option value="2">Modeling</option>
<option value="3">Xilinx ISE</option>
</select>
</span>
                                                
 </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="0">
            <span class="billingcodeCss"> <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_0__SelectedBillingCodesFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedBillingCodesFromList">
            <option value="">Budget-070</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="5">Budget-070</option>
            <option value="6">Budget-784</option>
            <option value="7">Cost Center-027</option>
            </select></span>                                              
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="Records[0].TimeRecords[0].ID" type="hidden" value="">
            <input class="meters" name="Records[0].TimeRecords[0].Meters" type="text" value="">
          </td>                                              
         
           <td class="rowtotal">10.00</td>
                                            

           <td>
            <input class="bs-checkbox mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline deleteRow" name="Records[0].DeleteRow" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Records[0].DeleteRow" type="hidden" value="false">
           </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
       <td><span class="project"> 
       <select class="form-control projectcodeid" id="Records" name="Records[1].SelectedProjectFromList"><option value="">Xilinx ISE</option>
<option value="1">Ventosanzap</option>
<option value="2">Modeling</option>
<option value="3">Xilinx ISE</option>

</select></span>
                                                
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="1">
       <span class="billingcodeCss"> <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_1__SelectedBillingCodesFromList" name="Records[1].SelectedBillingCodesFromList"><option value="">Bill-727                                          </option>
<option value="1">TIME CODE A                                       </option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Bill-727                                          </option>
<option value="3">Bill-561                                          </option>
<option value="4">Bill-281                                          </option>
</select></span>                                              
      </td>
         <td>
            <input name="Records[1].TimeRecords[0].ID" type="hidden" value="">
            <input class="meters" name="Records[1].TimeRecords[0].Meters" type="text" value="">
         </td>
                                           
                                            <!-- added row totals rowtotalmeters-->
                                            <td class="rowtotal">                                                
                                                0.00
                                            </td>                                            

                                            <td>
                                                <input class="bs-checkbox mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline deleteRow" name="Records[1].DeleteRow" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Records[1].DeleteRow" type="hidden" value="false">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        </table>
                                        
          <!--***********    End Main Table-->         
<hr />                            
<h4>Row template</h4>
 
<button type="button" id="CloneButton">Add Clone Row to table!</button>
 
 <table  id="rowtemplate">
<tr>
 <td>
    <span class="project"> <select class="form-control projectcodeid" id="Records_0__SelectedProjectFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedProjectFromList"><option value="">Default</option>
    <option value="0">Null</option>
<option value="1">Ventosanzap</option>
<option value="2">Modeling</option>
<option value="3">Xilinx ISE</option>
</select></span>
                                                
 </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="0">
            <span class="billingcodeCss"> <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_0__SelectedBillingCodesFromList" name="Records[0].SelectedBillingCodesFromList">
            <option value="">Default</option>
            <option value="0">Null</option>
            <option value="">Budget-070</option>
            <option value="5">Budget-070</option>
            <option value="6">Budget-784</option>
            <option value="7">Cost Center-027</option>
            </select></span>                                              
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="Records[0].TimeRecords[0].ID" type="hidden" value="">
            <input class="meters" name="Records[0].TimeRecords[0].Meters" type="text" value="">
          </td>                                              
         
           <td class="rowtotal">0.00</td>
                                            

           <td>
            <input class="bs-checkbox mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline deleteRow" name="Records[0].DeleteRow" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Records[0].DeleteRow" type="hidden" value="false">
           </td>
 </tr>

                                        
  </table>
```

**Please check the code snippet**

Comment: @transformer - check above answer

Comment: @transformer - This is my pleasure to help you. If this answer fulfills your requirement then accept and upvote it. It will helps other to find out correct answer. Thanks

Comment: I am testing will mark it, I have a small issue debugging

Comment: I am using bootstrap table it does not find/select the dropdown values `var drp2Value` are also empty. can you give me another suggestion to select/find the values